# @Html.EnumDropDownListFor() Additional information: Return type 'System.Int32' is not supported

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

@Html.EnumDropDownListFor() is throwing an error

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Return type 'System.Int32' is not supported."

Code from view

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.Label("Importance Level")
             @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.NoticeCategory)
            <span class="help-block">...</span>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Code from enum class

```
namespace OfficiumWebApp.Models.Enums
{
public enum NoticeCategories : byte
{
    [Display(Name= "High")]
    Hige = 1,

    [Display(Name = "Medium")]
    Medium = 2,

    [Display(Name = "Low")]
    Low = 3
}
```

I want the display names in the dropdown list so I'm not sure wht it's trying to return System.int32.

Any ideas where the problem could lie?

Thanks

EDIT: Forgot to include my view model code

```
    [Display(Name = "Notice Category")]
    public NoticeCategories? NoticeCategory  { get; set; }
```

EDIT 2: Stack trace

```
 at System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.EnumDropDownListFor[TModel,TEnum](HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, String optionLabel, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.EnumDropDownListFor[TModel,TEnum](HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, String optionLabel)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.EnumDropDownListFor[TModel,TEnum](HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression)
   at ASP._Page_Views_NoticeBoard_Create_cshtml.Execute() in .......................................................
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
```

Comment: Can you show the controller methods

Comment: What happens if you don't inherit from byte in the enum?

Comment: I could but it's only return View() inside of the method. I haven't added any custom code to the controller method.

Comment: Show the full stack-trace

Comment: Same thing @benni_mac_b

Comment: Also, are you sure it has something to do with the `Html.EnumDropDownListFor` call?

Comment: Yes I'm sure @haim770 as it doesn't happen when i take that line out

Comment: Added stack trace @haim770

Comment: Show the first 2-3 lines of your View (specifically, the @model directive)

Comment: Do you have `[Flags]` attribute on your enum?

Answer (score 0):

enum returns as a string listing. I guess you previously replaced the return with an enum where an int value is returned. Drop your table and re-create your database table with migration without enum. The problem will be eliminated. it coused your previous model.

OR

Add a call to ToString on the returned property to the expression.

Answer (score -1):

I had NoticeCategory defined as int in my notice class. I changeed this to IEnumerable